# I have a blank screen after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: boot, upgrade, xorg, screen, 14.10

I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, to Ubuntu 14.10. When I start my computer, I have a blank screen. If I plugin my laptop to my TV, at first only the TV turns on, but the login screen shows up on my TV, and when I log in my laptop's screen is turned on, and show Unity as expected. However, If I just let Ubuntu boot without any keys pressed, or if I press shift until the GRUB menu shows up and then select the "Ubuntu" option, I get a blank screen. In all situations where I get a blank screen, I hear the startup sound (i.e. I hear drums playing) which indicates that X has started up, just my notebooks screen isn't turned on for some reason. I never had this problem with all versions of Ubuntu, including non-LTS versions, from the earliest one I tried i.e. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Relevant details (that I can think of) are given below:

Type of laptop,
TOSHIBA Satellite L755D-11W: http://www.toshiba.co.il/en/discontinued-products/satellite-l755d-11w/.

`lspci | grep VGA`

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]  
BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6520G]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour     
[Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] (rev ff)
```

Comment: I cross posted this question here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/256412

Comment: Do CTRL+ALT+F2 and after that CTRL+ALT+F1 work?

Comment: They don't work, if I don't plug in my laptop to my TV.

Comment: Have you tried installing the proprietairy drivers with the Driver Manager tool? Connect it to your TV, install those drivers, disconnect your tv, reboot and try again.

Comment: I have installed the proprietary drivers, and they seem to work well.

Comment: I will propose it as an answer then :) I'm glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the proprietairy drivers for your system. They usually work better and they are a good idea trying if you don't get an image on your screen with the standard Ubuntu out of the box.

You can install the proprietairy drivers using the Driver Manager.